# Tableview Images doesn't load, but at times appears when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Tableview Images doesn't load, but at times appears when i scroll the page or else appears when i click on a cell.

NB: I am using `SDWebImage` [for lazy loading purposes](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyTableViewCell *c = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (c == nil)
    {
        c = [[MyTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                      reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    [c.imageView1 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0008_clear_sky_night.png"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pl.png"]];
```

Comment: Try to use c.imageView instead of c.imageView1 (hide your imageView1 temporary) for check will appear this artifact.

Comment: still the same. it appears at different cells. And when scrolled the positions change too

Comment: May i know the reason for the down vote?

Comment: is the place holder image also invisible or just lazy loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use SDWebImage+ActivityIndicator, it will show you the activity indicator when the image is downloading.

Dowload link - [SDWebImage+ActivityIndicator](https://github.com/JJSaccolo/UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage)

Replace as this method- `[c.imageView1 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:temp1] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"emptypic"] usingActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];`